# Limit Number Multiple Checkboxes in JS

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, limit

I have multiple checkboxes with limits but it doesn't work with JS like this

```
$(".checkbox-limit").on('change', function(evt) {
 var limit = parseInt($(this).parent().data("limit"));

if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
       alert("The limit is " + limit)
   }
});
```

and for html like this:

```
<div class="row js_check_two" data-limit="2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="1">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="2">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="3">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="4">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code not working,

Any suggestions would be gratefully receive!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your script to this -

```
            $(".checkbox-limit").on('change', function(evt) {

             var limit = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("data-limit"));
             console.log($('input.checkbox-limit:checked').length);

            if($('input.checkbox-limit:checked').length > limit) {
                   this.checked = false;
                   alert("The limit is " + limit);
               }
            });
```

Comment: this code doesn't work when using array, is there anything that needs to be replaced?

Comment: All the checkboxes must have class 'checkbox-limit' or you replace in the script by your checkboxes class.  Also the data-limit is the third parent in the present scenario. You may have to verify that too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".checkbox-limit").on('change', function(evt) {
 var limit = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("data-limit"));
 console.log($('input.checkbox-limit:checked').length);
 
 if($('input.checkbox-limit:checked').length > limit) {
 this.checked = false;
 alert("The limit is " + limit);
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row js_check_two" data-limit="2">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="1">1
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="2">2
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="3">3
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="4">4
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row js_check_two" data-limit="2">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="7">7
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="8">8
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="9">9
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-limit" value="10">10
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used that but effect for global